# Создание своих исключений Spring

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, oracle, spring-mvc

Есть стандартное исключение в Spring - `DuplicateKeyException`.

Т.е. если при запросе возвращается ошибка `ORA-00001`, то Spring распознает ее как `DuplicateKeyException`.

Я возвращаю свой код ошибки. Как мне зарегистрировать исключение для ошибки с моим кодом. Что бы я мог пользоваться им как `DuplicateKeyException`?

В Oracle я вызываю

```
raise_application_error (-20101, 'Failed to create');
```

И вот эту ошибку мне надо обработать.

Comment: Копайте в сторону [`SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.html).

Comment: Да вот уже накопал как создать CustomSQLErrorCodesTranslator  http://www.javacreed.com/handle-interruptedexceptions-with-jdbctemplate/ .
Пытаюсь понять, как и куда его прикрутить к проекту на MyBatis

Comment: У меня почему-то мимо обработчиков ошибки проходит. Т.е. ответ вернуля но null

Comment: А вариант вызывать `raise dup_val_on_index;` вместо `raise_application_error` не подойдет?

Comment: Я бы вызвал, но мне надо свое сообщение отослать клиенту. Такое чувство, что SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator не вызывается вообще, когда вызываем raise_application_error. Мимо проходит

Comment: Я, если что, spring не знаю, но могу предложить костыль на PL/SQL. Завернуть блок с `raise_application_error` в дополнительный `begin .. end`, перехватить исключение и выбросить вместо него любое стандартное исключение (например, `value_error` - ORA-06502). Spring (как я понимаю) сможет обработать это исключение, а дальше вам остается только выцарапать нужный кусок из текста ошибки.

Comment: А в value_error я смогу предать свое сообщение? Вся задумка в передаче текста о сформированной ошибке. Если да, по предложите как использовать value_error хотя бы псевдокодом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Костыль со стороны PL/SQL может выглядеть примерно так.
Исходный код (с перехватом и выводом ошибки):

```
begin
  raise_application_error (-20101, 'Failed to create');
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
end;
```

Здесь можно убедиться, что `SQLCODE` содержит значение `-20101`, а `SQLERRM` - `ORA-20101: Failed to create`.

Теперь перехватываем ошибку и генерируем `value_error`, а во внешнем блоке перехватываем, чтобы убедиться, что все работает:

```
begin
  begin
    raise_application_error (-20101, 'Failed to create');
  exception
    when others then
      raise value_error;
  end;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
end;
```

Теперь `SQLCODE` содержит значение `-6502`, а `SQLERRM` содержит 2 строки:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-20101: Failed to create
```

В этих строках будет ваше исходное сообщение, которое вы передали в `raise_application_error`, и второе сообщение от оракла. Их можно распарсить, первую строку выкинуть, а вторая и будет искомым текстом.

То есть ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
  begin
    /* некоторая логика, которая может привести к ошибке */
    raise_application_error (-20101, 'Failed to create');
  exception
    when others then
      raise value_error;
  end;
```

Comment: Гениально))) Надо попробовать. В принципе я так и с dup_val_on_index сделать смогу?

Comment: @ks_on_v Да, по идее, оракл будет выдвать наружу стандартное исключение, которое spring без проблем обрабатывает.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Answer (score 3):

Решение в [ранее данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/722982) - объединение двух сообщений об ошибке в один `SQLERRM`, было недокументированное [поведение в 11g](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=65d92dbf0c6eb3af114ec93b4e1c15f3), которое в более [новых версиях изменилось](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65d92dbf0c6eb3af114ec93b4e1c15f3).

Можно оба сообщения, из ошибки БД и свое кастомное, поместить в свое исключение, которое потом не составит труда извлечь из стека ошибки. Кроме того, *свое ислючение* обьявить как новый тип исключений, вот так:

```
create table t (id unique) as select 1 from dual
/

declare 
    myDuplicateKeyCode constant int := -20101;   
    myDuplicateKeyException exception;
    pragma exception_init (myDuplicateKeyException, myDuplicateKeyCode);
begin 
    begin 
        insert into t values (1);
    exception when dup_val_on_index then    
        raise_application_error (myDuplicateKeyCode, sqlerrm||chr(10)||
            '## my--> '||'Failed to create id=1');
    end ;    
exception when myDuplicateKeyException then 
    raise dup_val_on_index; 
end;
/
```

Выведет такой стек ошибки:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated
ORA-06512: at line 13
ORA-20101: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SH.SYS_C0012275) violated
## my--> Failed to create id=1
ORA-06512: at line 9
```